# Dynamically change values in form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

I was trying to pass the value according to the selections of products to the third-party payment platform; therefore, I use the code as below: 
**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="ItemDesc" onchange="passPrice();">
    <option value="prodA">prodA</option>
    <option value="prodB">prodB</option>
    <option value="prodC">prodC</option>
</select>
<div id="price" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" id="priceAmt" name="Amt" value="0">            
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var prc = new Array();
var theForm = document.forms["shoppingCart"];
prc["prodA"] = 100;
prc["prodB"] = 200;
prc["prodC"] = 300;

function getPrice(){
    var prodPrice = 0;
    var prod = theForm.elements["sel1"];
    prodPrice = prc[prod.value];
    return prodPrice;
}
function passPrice(){
    document.getElementById("priceAmt").value = getPrice();
}
```

When I tested it, the error message showed that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null". And then when I use document.getElementById("priceAmt") again, it returned *null*.
However, it worked all right when I used the console to execute the codes line-by-line as follows:

```
getPrice(); //it returns 100 by default
document.getElementById("priceAmt").value = getPrice(); //it also returns 100
```

I've searched relevant keywords but didn't find similar situations. What might be the problem in this case?

Edited Oct 26th:
I solved the problem by dropping the input element `priceAmt` out of the division but am still curious why the original way didn't work.

Comment: Two possibilities : either the script executes before the corresponding HTML in your page (missing `document.ready)`, or the HTML is dynamically loaded then added to the DOM. In both cases, I think the script executes before the HTML elements exists.

Comment: Is there any solution to solve this problem (missing `document.ready`)?

Comment: Oh yes, there is a solution... add `document.ready`. https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/running-code-when-the-document-is-ready-15/